# Find text in a row without duplicating

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dst82.png)I need to find a formula that will look through column A and find the first cell with data and copy it to column c. I have attached a picture with a better explanation.

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
a             1           =A2
b             2           =A2 But not equal to C1, if A2=C2, then = A3, IF A3 = A1, then = A             4
c             3 
c             4 
d             5
```

Comment: I don't see a picture...

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1504007/edit) to clarify what the desired result is? Maybe reproduce the current table with the expected result, followed by and explanation of how you arrive to it.

Comment: Not very understand your problem. Could you explain this problem more clearly?

Comment: Are you trying to find unique values in column A and put those in column C?

Comment: So what I eventually want to do, is be able to find unique values from column a to generate a list on column c that does not duplicate the value from column a, this will allow me to find one value from each cell in column a while validating the previous cells in column c to keep from replicating.the. I would attach a picture but It doesn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:    (pictures data in A2:B6, as in the description)

```
=SUMIF(A2:A6,UNIQUE(A2:A6),B2:B6)
```

`UNIQUE()` was "officially" added in September 2018 so probably was available in November 2019, even with Excel's painful lag after announcements.

Even if not, people **searching TODAY** (after 2021), deserve an answer using things available as currently as possible. And if 2022 or 2028 brings better, the question merits another, more up-to-date, answer then.

Formula is very straightforward. `UNIQUE()` gives a list of unique entries in the key column. `SUMIF()` uses that for input in calculating the desired summations of each kind of item in the lookup list.

Note that if a blank cell is present in that list, it will be returned by `UNIQUE()`. A minor issue, practically-wise, for most uses of the data, but if an issue, one could either seek out explanation for the occurrence/s and resolve that/those issues and so have "whole" data, or one could eliminate it elsewise. Lots of tricks available depending upon purpose, use, and layout of one's spreadsheet in the relevant output region.

*(Maybe the (painfully announced, but nowhere near to release to us hoi polloi) `LAMBDA()` function will allow for simple removal of blanks returned by `UNIQUE()`. Helpful since, of course, Excel will never now change `UNIQUE()` to have a parameter to ignore blanks. Hope they use this probably a year and a half wait from announcement to delivery to learn more about `LAMBDA()`'s important capability needs than they did with `UNIQUE()`.)*